# How to replace particular values based on condition by using tf.where()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to replace values under condition.
NumPy version would go like this

```
intensity=np.where(
  np.abs(intensity)<1e-4,
  1e-4,
  intensity)
```

But TensorFlow has a bit different usage for tf.where()
When I tried this

```
intensity=tf.where(
  tf.math.abs(intensity)<1e-4,
  1e-4,
  intensity)
```

I got this error

```
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 4 for 'Select' (op: 'Select') with input shapes: [?,512,512,1], [], [?,512,512,1].
```

Does that mean I should 4 dimensional tensor for `1e-4`?

Answer (score 2):

Following code passed the error

```
# Create an array which has small value (1e-4),  
# whose shape is (2,512,512,1)
small_val=np.full((2,512,512,1),1e-4).astype("float32")

# Convert numpy array to tf.constant
small_val=tf.constant(small_val)

# Use tf.where()
intensity=tf.where(
  tf.math.abs(intensity)<1e-4,
  small_val,
  intensity)

# Error doesn't occur
print(intensity.shape)
# (2, 512, 512, 1)
```

Comment: You can also directly do `small_val = tf.full(tf.shape(intensity), tf.constant(1e-4, dtype=intensity.dtype))`, or even just `small_val = 1e-4 + tf.zeros_(intensity)`.